# assigning a foreign key to a table that is yet to be inputted

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have this table `Recipients`, which "should" contain an `AddressID` foreign key from the `Addresses` table.

My form asks details from the shipper, which must include the recipient and the address where his package must be delivered. Whatever data he inputs there shall be received by `Addresses` and `Recipients` table respectively, then I have to make the same `Address` data to be the foreign key to the `Recipients` table, but both data are yet to be entered, one way or another.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework?

Comment: No, I don't. This was supposed to be our school project mainly just to highlight how tables interact with each other and we could learn how to make entity relationship diagrams

Comment: did you consider using two forms instead than one (in the first you ask name, surname etc, and in the second you ask the address), so you can do two different Insert queries (in that case I would put the foreign key in the table addresses to ask anagraphical data first)